# What is difference between Java's int[] and i32 in Apache Thrift

Tags: java, arrays, thrift

Can anyone help me understand difference between `int[]` in Java and `i32` (`NumericDataArray`) in Apache Thrift? And when the latter should be used? Also, do we have anything like `i32` for strings?

Comment: `i32` is not a standard thing.

Comment: Well for starters, one is part of the standard, and the other is a third party API.

Comment: What third party library are you using? We need that to answer your question.

Comment: Afaik there is no `NumericDataArray` in thrift, but there is one in [Mona Lisa](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~monalisa/open/repository/documentation/javadoc/binaryIO_v3_1/uk_ac_ox_physics/monalisa/BinaryIO/NumericDataArray.I32.html)  Are you sure you are using/want to use Thrift?

Answer (score 2):

From [Thrift Types](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/types/)

> Base Types
>
> The base types were selected with the goal of simplicity and clarity
>   rather than abundance, focusing on the key types available in all
>   programming languages.
>
> ```
> bool: A boolean value (true or false)
> byte: An 8-bit signed integer
> i16: A 16-bit signed integer
> i32: A 32-bit signed integer
> i64: A 64-bit signed integer
> double: A 64-bit floating point number
> string: A text string encoded using UTF-8 encoding
> ```

So `i32` is a 32-bit signed integer which is mapped to java `int`.

You have no arrays in thrift, but container-types:

> Containers
>
> Thrift containers are strongly typed containers that map to commonly
>   used and commonly available container types in most programming
>   languages.
>
> There are three container types:
>
> list: An ordered list of elements. Translates to an STL vector, Java
>   ArrayList, native arrays in scripting languages, etc.
>
> set: An unordered set of unique elements. Translates to an STL set, Java
>   HashSet, set in Python, etc. Note: PHP does not support sets, so it is
>   treated similar to a List
>
> map: A map of strictly unique keys to values. Translates to an STL map, Java HashMap, PHP associative array,
>   Python/Ruby dictionary, etc. While defaults are provided, the type
>   mappings are not explicitly fixed. Custom code generator directives
>   have been added to allow substitution of custom types in various
>   destination languages.
>
> Container elements may be of any valid Thrift Type.

These containers are mapped to the according Java `List`, `Set` and `Map`.

So if you are using thrift and need to transport a collection of `int`-values, you will use a list-container of type `int32` like `list<i32>`, which will result in a `java.util.ArrayList<Integer>` on the java-side.

No need to worry about `String`: There is a base type `string` in thrift, which is mapped to java `java.lang.String`. So you just define a `string` in thrift and you will have `java.lang.String` in your generated java-code.

Comment: In fact there's binary too (although the docs still indicate otherwise), which is an ByteBuffer, or more essentially a byte[]. Just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @pink panther Feel free to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

An int[] its a simple array, normally used to do simple things, eg. store temporary data.

The i32 it's a third part library, like William said.

If you do not have a very specific issue, I recommend to you use a int[], but if you need to use i32, maybe can you take a look in this link: http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/protocol/TType.html